# Why is my accept rate 88%

Tags: support

I have accepted an answer on every question that I posed, except for the question that got closed? Do closed questions count towards the accept rate?

Comment: Probably over a month

Comment: [Accept rate is no longer displayed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate/164654#164654).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accept rate is updated every 24 hours (or so). Closed questions **do not** count when calculating the rate.

The mouse-over text says you've accepted 7 of 8 eligible questions. When I look at your account profile I see 11 questions, so three of them aren't eligible.

[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/how-do-i-use-the-emulator-with-appinventor) appears to be the only question (with answers) that you haven't accepted an answer.

But, honestly, 88% is a great accept rate. Don't worry about it.

More information can be found in this [FAQ on Accept Rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work).